# Holder continuity, brwonian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $B$ stand for a brownian motion on a finite interval $[0,1]$. If i am not wrong, i think that there exists a positive constant $c$, such that almost surely, for h small enough , for all $0< t < 1- h$

\begin{align}
|B(t+h)-B(t)| < c\sqrt{h\log(1/h)}
\end{align}
or something like this. As a result

\begin{align}
\bigg|\frac{B(t+h)-B(t)}{h}\bigg| < K(h) 
\end{align}

Am i correct ?

Comment: Are you user @peter5?

Comment: yes, i wanted a cool nickname :P

Comment: "yes, i wanted a cool nickname :P" Are you aware that the site forbids to use several user accounts? Let me suggest to close all your accounts except one and to avoid reposting duplicates of your own questions.

Comment: in fact i didn't